# .Bat script doesn't change Desktop wallpaper immediately

Tags: batch-file, wallpaper

I'm trying to change the Desktop wallpaper between 2 images after every seconds, however after few seconds of execution it doesn't work anymore, is there a way to do it but really fast, so I can change it from seconds to milliseconds(to update it between an image that gets updated via an other program), but for now this simple script doesn't do the intended task:

```
@echo off
:Loop

reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f 
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\Etudiant\Desktop\3.bmp" /f 
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperStyle /f
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /t REG_SZ /d 2 /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 
TIMEOUT 1 

reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f 
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\Etudiant\Desktop\2.bmp" /f 
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperStyle /f
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /t REG_SZ /d 2 /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 
TIMEOUT 1 

GOTO Loop
exit
```

Comment: I cannot spot the difference between the two blocks...

Comment: Typing mistake, the second bloc contains an image called 2.bmp instead